# Migrating Mule 3.6 to Mule 3.7 Nullpayload test

Tags: mule, mule-el

I'm migrating my mule project from version 3.6 to 3.7. In version 3.6 the test #[NullPayload.getInstance().equals(payload)] return true when my payload is null, however in version 3.7 when the payload is null this tests return false.

I saw in the 3.7 release note that the bug MULE-6427 (#[payload == null] is not true when the payload is NullPayload) was fix.

Is this correct?

Now I have to test payload == null?

it's a bug #[NullPayload.getInstance().equals(payload)] return false when the payload is null in version 3.7?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850469/migrating-mule-3-6-to-mule-3-7-nullpointerexception-calling-method-with-null-pay

Comment: It's two diferent question, the question you posted is related to the invoke mule component, this is related to Mule Expression Language

Answer (score 3):

`#[payload == null]` work in 3.7 for NullPayload now.

Comment: I Know, as I said in my question this was in the release note of version 3.7. I want to know the reason or if it's a bug

Comment: Hi, don't think he was a bug at least technically speaking. Conceptually was surely confusing that's why mule improved it.

Comment: Just to be clear I want to know if it's a bug #NullPayload.getInstance().equals(payload)] return false when the payload is null in version 3.7