# Migrating Mule 3.6 to Mule 3.7 NullPointerException calling method with null payload

Tags: mule, mule-el

I'm migrating my mule project from version 3.6 to 3.7. In version 3.6 I was able to use invoker calling a method passing payload as an argument.

Now in version 3.7 if I do that I get `NullPointerException`, when payload is `null`, in class `InvokerMessageProcessor`, line 272, when the following test is executed:

```
if (!(type.isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass())))
```

Because when payload is `null` `arg` is `null`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there was a change in the way Mule treats *emptiness* and `null` values from Mule 3.6+ to 3.7+, This is the way the validations used to be in **Mule 3.6.x** for different kind of processors and components:

- MEL (Mule Expression Language): `Payload == null`: false
- MEL: `Payload is NullPayload`: true
- MEL: `Payload is org.mule.transport.NullPayload`: true
- Groovy: `Payload instanceof org.mule.transport.NullPayload`: true
- Groovy: `Payload == null`: false

  Now, in **Mule 3.7.x**:
- MEL: `Payload == null`: true
- MEL: `Payload is NullPayload`: false
- MEL: `Payload is org.mule.transport.NullPayload`: false
- Groovy: `Payload instanceof org.mule.transport.NullPayload`: true
- Groovy: `Payload == null`: false

Comment: I understood that the change happened, but what I want to know is if MuleSoft has to correct their code because of the NullPointerException that it's happennig in class InvokerMessageProcessor

Comment: Nop, that is not gonna happen, the answer I provided you I got it directly from Mulesoft Support because I fell in the same situation before and for them this is an Improvement in the functionality.